# Redirection to incorrect page

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to redirect using a button on a custom control (code below). the following is written to the debug toolbar which is where I want to go:
destBack=https://www.example.com/MyAttachments . But I instead get a Error 404 page and the following line appears on the server console:
HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception [/site/home.nsf/https:/www.example.com/MyAttachments.xsp] Anonymous

I do have a reditection rule as follows:

> Description:   MyAttachmentsView
>
> Type of rule:  Redirection
>
> Incoming URL pattern:  */MyAttachments
>
> Redirect to this URL:  /site/home.nsf/MyProfileAttachmentsView.xsp
>
> Send 301 Redirect:

If I copy and paste the destBack URL I get where I want to go.

My SSJS code behind the button is as follows

```
importPackage(com.example);
var destination = configBean.getValue("HostURL")+"MyAttachments";
dBar.info("destBack="+destination)
context.redirectToPage(destination)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code to redirect
externalCtx = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
externalCtx.redirect("http://www.tlcc.com");

See http://linqed.eu/2011/07/27/xpages-server-vs-client-side-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

`context.redirectToPage` is designed to redirect the XPages runtime to an XPage within the current database. That's why the URL in the error message contains "/site/home.nsf/" (the current database path) and "https:/www.example.com/MyAttachments.xsp" (the URL you're defining).

If you want to change the whole URL, you need to change the URL client-side, not server-side, e.g. with `location.href="...."`

Comment: Thanks Paul - Looks like I need to change my approach.